# Amazon S3 and Cloudfront - Publish file uploaded as hashed filename

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

**Technologies:**

- Python3
- Boto3
- AWS

I have a project built using Python3 and Boto3 to communicate with a bucket in Amazon S3 service.

The process is that a user posts images to the service; these' images are uploaded to an S3 bucket, and can be served through amazon cloudfront using a hashed file name instead of the real file name.

**Example:**

- (S3) Upload key: /category-folder/png/image.png
- (CloudFront) Serve: `http://d2949o5mkkp72v.cloudfront.net/d824USNsdkmx824`

I want to file uploaded to S3, appear as hash number as file name in cloudfront server.

Does anyone have knowledge that makes S3 or cloudfront automatically convert and publish a file-name to a hash name.

Comment: The cloudfront cdn just provide the urn for the contents, and appear as url  ... so , what is your problem?

Comment: I don't want to use the full path + filename, I want to use a hashed version (like spotify for example) - is this possible? as in built in, or do I have to hash it myself?

Comment: @belthazorNv you have to hash it yourself

Comment: I just edit your question , check whether it is appropriate server your needs.
p/s: I have similar requirement,  I just wrote a wrapper to do the conversion. Because there is no "use SHA256 hash as file name option" , nor with auto-zip. etc

Comment: I see... that pretty much sums it up. - Thank you guys

Comment: Not sure if you guys agree but I'd go with uuid1 for this, guaranteed to have no collisions as a unique ID.

Comment: uuid not adequate, you may end up putting same file with different ID. A hash allow you to build process to avoid uploading same large file again.

Comment: No duplicate files will be added; I store the filename in db, and key (uuid), and I compare when uploading.

Comment: uuid should be fine, except there is many version uuid , even inside RFC has a few version. ;-D

Comment: Should be! :) - uuid1 has a very good reputation! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to suffice my needs I created the fields needed to maintain the keys (to make them unique; both on S3 and in my mongodb)

**Fields**:

```
original_file_name = my_file_name
file_category = my_images, children, fun 
file_type = image, video, application
key = uniqueID
```

With the mentioned fields; then one can check if the key exists by simply searching for the key, the new file_name, the category, and the type; if it exists in the database then file exists.

**To generate the unique id:**

```
def get_key(self):
    from uuid import uuid1
    return uuid1().hex[:20]
```

This limits the ID to the length of 20 characters.